# Create time bins and assign data to correct bin

Tags: r, lubridate

I would like to create a sequence of 30 minute time bins over a 24 hour period which I have done using

```
seq(as.POSIXct("2018-03-25"). as.POSIXct("2018-03-26"), by = "30 min")
```

I have a set of data with specific times such as 25/03/2018 05:08 and 25/03/2018 18:39. I would like to be able to create a data frame with the list of time bins, and then 'present' or 'absent' depending whether a data point exists which falls within any of the time bins or not.

I thought that I could do this using interval with lubridate, but I haven't been able to create the sequence of bins. I had hoped to use `%within%` to match the data points to the bins but I am relatively new to R and am not able to do this.

My data are like as follows, with detections of sharks at different locations (station in dataset). In my actual data I have 41894 observations spanning a three month period and need to match these to the correct time bin for each day over the 3 month period.

```
detect_date        Station  
25/03/2018 00:09    SS01   
25/03/2018 01:17    SS03 
25/03/2016 14:37    SS04 
25/03/2016 23:43    SS04
```

The output I would like in the end would be something like as follows.

```
bin                Location  
25/03/2018 00:00    SS01 
25/03/2018 00:30   Absent 
25/03/2018 01:00    SS03
```

Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: It's difficult to tell without any dummy data, but I think I'd approach your problem with `lubridate::floor_date(date, "30 minutes")` instead of creating the bins in the first place. Would that work for you? In case it doesn't, please share your data and desired output so we can try and help.

Comment: Thanks! I've appended the question with some more detail. I think I need to have the time bins in order to determine presence or absence over a time period, as I currently only have presence data. @PavoDive

Comment: @Henrik Thanks! I've just removed that part about individuals as otherwise I think my question isn't specific enough. I think I can deal with that section myself after I manage to assign the observations to the right bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to solve this using `data.table` and `lubridate` and sticking to my idea of using `floor_date`.

```
# load packages
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# define a vector evenly spaced each 30 minutes:
b <- data.table(dates = seq(as.POSIXct("2018-03-25", tz = "UTC"), 
                            as.POSIXct("2018-03-26", tz = "UTC"), 
                            by = "30 min"))

# reproduce data
dt <- data.table(detect_date = as.character(c("25/03/2018 00:09", "25/03/2018 01:17", "25/03/2016 14:37", "25/03/2016 23:43")), 
                 Station = c("SS01", "SS03", "SS04", "SS04"), 
                 Individual = c("A", "B", "C", "B"))

# convert detect_date to date format
dt[, detect_date := dmy_hm(detect_date)]

# make a join
dt[, .(Location = Station, Individual), by = .(dates = floor_date(detect_date, "30 minutes"))][b, on = "dates"]
```

Comment: Just a query- when I applied this to my real data, it worked great but there is one bin at 2pm which came up as NA when it should have listed an individual and station- any idea why this could be? @PavoDive